# Is astigmatism a type of retinopathy?

Tags: terminology

Astigmatism is a common vision condition that causes blurred vision. It occurs when the cornea is irregularly shaped.

Retinopathy is any damage to the retina of the eyes, which may cause vision impairment. Retinopathy often refers to retinal vascular disease, or damage to the retina caused by abnormal blood flow.

So, is astigmatism a type of retinopathy?

Comment: You observed that astigmatism is caused by a misshaped cornea, so why would you think it involves the retina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cornea is in a different part of the eye than the retina, hence astigmatism is not a disease of the retina.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_eye#/media/File:Schematic_diagram_of_the_human_eye_en.svg